# CMB radiation and holography

Tags: cosmology, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

If in principle someone have the exact data of the CMB of our universe and unlimited computability power, to what extent it is possible to determine how the universe should look like? Does it fully determines the later time structure of the universe or the same information could be matched to more than one universe?